# Tpl direct print html in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I craete a custom module for add textarea in product backoffice . When I print this textarea in tpl file in print direct html link this

[image]

I use this to print in tpl

```
 {if isset($belvg_textarea)}
    <div>
     {$belvg_textarea|unescape:'html'}
     {$belvg_textarea|escape:'html'}
    </div>
 {/if}
```

and this in module php file for display

```
 public function hookDisplayFooterProduct($params) {
    $id_product = Tools::getValue('id_product');
    $sampleObj = Belvg_Sample::loadByIdProduct($id_product);
    if(!empty($sampleObj) && isset($sampleObj->id)){
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'belvg_textarea' => $sampleObj->textarea,
        ));
    }

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/frontend/sample.tpl');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `nofilter` beacause prestashop 1.7 escape html by default so your html tags will be displayed

in your tpl file :

```
{if isset($belvg_textarea)}
    <div>
     {$belvg_textarea nofilter}
    </div>
 {/if}
```